# Actionbar add padding between icon and text

Tags: android, tabs, android-actionbar, icons, padding

**I have a Actionbar Tab with icon and text:**

```
actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab()
              .setText("Tab1")
              .setIcon(R.drawable.image));
```

I want add a **"10dp" padding between the icon and text** of the tab and use "styles":

```
<item name="android:actionBarTabStyle">@style/MyTabStyle</item>
```

and

```
<style name="MyTabStyle" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">10dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingRight">10dp</item>
</style>
```

Example:

(image)Tab1 --> (image)"10dp"Tab1

I solved momentarily with: **.setText("  Tab1")**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with margin or layout_margin :

```
    <style name="MyTabStyle" parent="AppTheme">
        <item name="android:layout_marginLeft">10dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginRight">10dp</item>
    </style>
```